# Beginner problem with crashing code to lookup class or text on website

Tags: javascript

I write this code to check if on my website is a text and if its not then it should send me a notification thru slack. When I run it on VSC it crushes after some time like maybe 15 min or something like that.

I want to make it nice to put it on a server and run it remotly but need to be sure that will not crash every so often. I want to use it to check some websites for changing information on them and if they will change or be gone then send me notification. Best bit it works but crashes and don't know why :(

Can someone maybe help or pinpoint what it can be the problem? It will be better that this tool can just see text instead of class but I don't know how to do that.

```
//Puppeteer library
const pt= require('puppeteer')
const axios = require('axios')
process.setMaxListeners(0);
async function getText(){
   //launch browser in headless mode
   const browser = await pt.launch()
   //browser new page
   const page = await browser.newPage()
   //launch URL
   await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); 
   //website
   await page.goto('https://mieciusio.pl/kontakt.html')

    

   //identify element
   if (await page.$("[class='p-style btn-resize-mode label-bloc-2-style label-1-style']"))
 
   console.log("found")
   else //console.log("not found")
   axios.post(' https://hooks.slack.com/services/MYUniqeID', {text: 'Its changed'})
   

    
     
   
}

setInterval(getText, 12000)
```

Try to find it online on YT but it's hard I was looking in a lot of tut's but can't find right one to work on finding text on website or not to crush because I don't know why crashes.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with puppeteer, but since you're creating new instance of browser on each function call, don't you have to close it somewhere? Seems like it just stack on background untill some limits exceeded

Comment: how to instead of open new one to refresh that open one?

Comment: I meant that you could leave your `getText` function as it is with little addition of `browser.close()` in the end, but if you will to refresh you're probably looking for [`reload`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.reload/)

Comment: will try will browser.close()